# Matching the value between colon and semicolon

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple question: my long text is full of: `text:value;text:value;...`.
My question is how do you get all values between `:` and `;`

My half-correct(?) pattern is:
`text:(.*);.text:`

Could someone show me a better way?

Comment: split strings based on ';' and then based on ':'

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I know about this way, but should not use it. Please don't ask why :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the regex you are searching:

```
text:([^;]*);
```

Where `[^;]` matches everything but the semicolon.

Comment: Would you then mark my answer as the correct one (The big tick on the left side)? People on Stackoverflow won't answer your questions anymore if they see that you don't accept the answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pattern: `\w+:(?<value>\w+);`

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\w+:(?<value>\w+);");

foreach (Match match in pattern.Matches("text:bar;text:foo;"))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["value"].Value);
```

Prints:

```
bar
foo
```